# IPtable rule to limit number of TCP connections on my PC

Tags: linux, networking, google-chrome, iptables

I have a limit on the number of TCP connections that I can make in my network. If I make more than 100 TCP connections, I get banned for a few minutes. My GoogleChrome in linux opens a lot of connections and I get frequently blocked from the network.(from `netstat -pctn`)

Can some one help me with an iptable rule to limit connections of my Chrome or better my PC?

Answer (score 0):

I will not answer your question because what you are proposing will limit the functionality of your system. I will instead suggest a smart alternative to complying with your network's silly rules.

You should use a VPN, routing all traffic thru it. This way, your network firewall/proxy would see only one connection (and, depending on the type of VPN, that could even be a UDP connection, thus leaving you with 0 (zero) TCP connections), and you would never fall afoul of this stupid rule.

You may either setup the server at home, or rent a cheap VPS (I have one with unlimited traffic for 3 US$/mo) and setup the server there. Either way, you would respect the letter of the rule without renouncing the full functionality of your system.